# Edit button WHEN-BUTTON-IS-PRESSED in Oracle forms builder

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

I'm going to create a edit button that will edit the contents the forms named MEMBERS in Oracle Forms Builder. I already did the ADD button and this is the code (this button is located at the MEMBERS_ADD form):

NOTE: The name of the table is MEMBER also and these are the columns of the member table

```
-member_id  
-firstname  
-lastname    
-gender  
-address    
-contact   
-type   
-yearlevel  
-status
```

---

```
begin
commit_form;
first_record;
LOOP
INSERT INTO MEMBERS
SELECT * FROM MEMBERS WHERE MEMBER_ID = MEMBER_ID;
EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD='TRUE';
    NEXT_RECORD;
    END LOOP;
FIRST_RECORD;
 
COMMIT;
     MESSAGE('RECORD SAVED!');
     MESSAGE(' ',no_acknowledge);
end;
```

---

This is the code im using for the edit button:

```
DECLARE
  pl PARAMLIST:=GET_PARAMETER_LIST('PL_EDIT_MEM');
BEGIN
  IF NOT ID_NULL(pl) THEN
    DESTROY_PARAMETER_LIST(pl);
  END IF;
  pl:=CREATE_PARAMETER_LIST('PL_EDIT_MEM');
  ADD_PARAMETER(pl, 'P_MODE', TEXT_PARAMETER, 'EDIT');
  ADD_PARAMETER(pl, 'P_MEMBER_ID', TEXT_PARAMETER, :MEMBERS.MEMBER_ID);
  CALL_FORM('MEMBER',NO_HIDE,DO_REPLACE,NO_QUERY_ONLY,pl);
END;
```

the code gives me an error : FRM-40010: Cannot read from MEMBER

Answer (score 0):

Your edit button prepares a [Parameter list](http://www.1neveling.de/oracle/parameter_list.htm), populates the parameters and then does a call_form to open a form called "member".

You're getting FRM-40010 error because Forms server can't find member form executible file(member.fmx). I hope you have compiled the form and created the fmx file. If not, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to compile all and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to generate the fmx file.

---

As far the first piece code, the loop makes no sense, because it's just doing a self join (see the bit: `WHERE MEMBER_ID = MEMBER_ID` - I hope that's a typo?) and then inserting into the same table it's selecting from from

Comment: I did the CTRL + K. but it does nothing :(then in the part second part, i tried creating a dummy account of member. then that will serve as second from. but the records i'm entering isn't saving. what to do ? :((

Comment: Then i got this new error

FRM-40400 No changes to save

Comment: that should have been Ctrl+T to generate the fmx. I don't know how you've designed the form, but if it's configured as a datablock with table as source, commit_form will save entered data to the table which the datablock is set as source. If it's 40400 then forms detects nothing has changed so shows that message

Comment: but it still saves the info i add whenever it says no changes to save

Comment: that's because you're doing a `commit_form` and then doing a commit again

Comment: i checked the directory and i already have a fmx. :( it's just that, i really don't know where the error is coming from :(